# What is the spectrum of the Earth's albedo?

Tags: climate-science, scattering-cross-section

I was recently discussing climate change with a friend and was surprised (and embarrassed) to learn that the heat capacity of CO${}_2$ is not higher than that of nitrogen contrary to my assertions.  After further research, I found that the relevant capture cross sections account for the greenhouse effect.

I wanted run some calculations, but, while I know how to determine the cross sections of elements and compounds, I don't know what the average spectrum of Earth's albedo is.

Where can I find this information?  What is the average spectrum of Earth's albedo?

Answer (score 2):

There [CERES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clouds_and_the_Earth%27s_Radiant_Energy_System) satellite has been measuring light reflected from Earth. In principle the raw data is available [from NASA](http://ceres.larc.nasa.gov/) though I imagine some work will be necessary to process it.